Dirac delta Composition with a function Proof
One of the properties of Dirac delta is that for a smooth function $f(x)$, we have
$$\delta(f(x))=\sum_{i}{\frac{\delta(x-a_i)}{|f'(a_i)|}}\hspace{0.5cm}(1)$$
Suppose I have a (continuous?) function $g(x)$ and $a_i$'s be the roots of $f(x)$, then
$$\delta(f(x))[g(x)]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{g(x)\delta(f(x))dx}=\sum_i\int_{a_i-\epsilon}^{a_i+\epsilon}g(x)\delta(f(x))dx\hspace{0.5cm}(2)$$
Considering the Taylor's series of $f(x)$ about $a_i$, which is $f(x)=f(a_i)+f'(a)(x-a_i)+\frac{f''(a_i)(x-a_i)^2}{2!}+\frac{f'''(a_i)(x-a_i)^3}{3!}+\mathcal{O}(x^4)$ and plugging it to the above equality, results in the below equality
$$\delta(f(x))[g(x)]=\sum_i{\int_{a_i-\epsilon}^{a_i+\epsilon}g(x)\delta(f'(a_i)+\frac{f''(a_i)(x-a_i)^2}{2!}+\frac{f'''(a_i)(x-a_i)^3}{3!}+...)dx}=\sum_i{\int_{a_i-\epsilon}^{a_i+\epsilon}g(x)\bigg(\ \delta(f'(a_i)+\delta(\frac{f''(a_i)(x-a_i)}{2!}+\delta({\frac{f'''(a_i)(x-a_i)^3}{3!}}+...)\bigg)dx}\hspace{0.5cm}(3)$$
which can also be expanded as below since delta is a linear functional (I guess so?)
$$\sum_i\int_{a_i-\epsilon}^{a_i+\epsilon}\bigg(g(x)\delta(f'(a_i)+g(x)\delta(\frac{f''(a_i)(x-a_i)}{2!}+g(x)\delta({\frac{f'''(a_i)(x-a_i)^3}{3!}}+...\bigg)dx\hspace{0.5cm}(4)$$
If I can find a way to discard the terms such as $g(x)\delta(\frac{f''(a_i)(x-a_i)}{2!}\big)$ and $g(x)\delta({\frac{f'''(a_i)(x-a_i)^3}{3!}}\big)$ and so on, I can prove $(1)$. I also derived that
$$\int_{a_i-\epsilon}^{a_i+\epsilon}{g(x)\delta(\frac{f^{(n)}(a_i)(x-a_i)^n}{n!})dx}=|\frac{n!}{f^{(n)}(a_i)}|\int_{a_i-\epsilon}^{a_i+\epsilon}{g(x)\delta\big((x-a_i)^n\big)dx}=|\frac{n!}{f^{(n)}(a_i)}|\int_{a_i-\epsilon}^{a_i+\epsilon}{g(a_i)\delta\big((x-a_i)^n\big)dx}=|\frac{n!}{f^{(n)}(a_i)}|.g(a_i).\int_{a_i-\epsilon}^{a_i+\epsilon}\delta\big((x-a_i)^n\big)dx=|\frac{n!}{f^{(n)}(a_i)}|.g(a_i).\int_{-\epsilon}^{+\epsilon}\delta(u^n)du\hspace{0.5cm}(5)$$
I want to prove that that $(5)$ is zero or negligible so I can prove $(1)$. How can I do it if it is possible at all?
